# Bootstrap expanded Dropdown dosen't get Open in Mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-browser

I am using **Bootstrap v3.0.2** with `bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js` to make dropdowns visible on hover in main navigation menu.

For expanded menus I have removed `href` and put `#`. I noticed that expanded menus are not working in Safari.

Comment: Do you mean that it stopped working after modified the `href` attributes?

Comment: This issue is only in safari. Even I keep href and checked after that but still expanded bootstrap dropdown is not getting collapsed only in safari.